# Making mchoice question behaves as schoice in `exams2moodle()` of package exams

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm using the **rexams package** to create questionaries for Moodle with the `exams2moodle()` function.
I would like to create an `mchoice` question with, for instance, 5 true answers and 10 false answers. Ok, but I would like that this mchoice question **behaves as an `schoice`** question; that is, that finally an schoice question is created from the mchoice.
The final created schoice question would have 1 true answer (taken randomly from the 5 true answers in the mchoice question) and 3 false answers (from the 10 false answers in the mchoice).
I think this is possible within the rexams package, at least I remember to have seen it, but I  cannot do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.r-exams.org/tutorials/first_steps/#meta-information):

> `exshuffle` is set to 5 so that 1 correct and 4 random wrong
>   alternatives are subsampled and shuffled

An MWE (in `.Rnw`):

```
\exname{Test}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{11100000} % true, true, true and the others are false
\exshuffle{5}
\begin{question}
  Question text.
  \begin{answerlist}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \item 5
  \end{answerlist}
\end{question}
```

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* As already explained by @uzsolt, you simply need to set `exshuffle` to `5` and `extype` to `schoice`. Then the sampling will be performed as you indicated.

*Worked example:* For illustration you can consider the `capitals` exercise provided with the R/exams package: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/capitals/ (added in R version 2.3-5).

As also discussed in an accompanying YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI5xG7Y0hQ0), this exercise is inlucded in the package as an `mchoice` exercise with six false and five true answer alternatives. As `exshuffle` is set to `5` this will randomly select five answer alternatives, making sure that at least one is true and at least one is false.

But if you modify the same exercise template to `schoice`, it will employ the sampling that you described: Only one of the true answers alternatives is selected and four of the false ones.

Comment: Thanks again!! Sorry because the answer was in the R-exams website, and in fact I remenbered to have seen it ... but time was runing  I had some exams to make. Thanks for all the work you have done in exams package.